# How to change value for "listView1.FocusedItem.Index"?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I am adding and removing items to listView, **in Windows Mobile**.
I am using "listView1_SelectedIndexChanged" function, which is called only if I press on a different Row index than the last press. 
Is there a way to change "listView1.FocusedItem.Index" variable (give it a non-valid value or something), so the function will be called each time I press on an item in the list, and not only when it's a new index?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

What version of Windows Mobile are you using? Not all versions support the same things.

You can really only read the [FocusedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.focuseditem%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) from the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) control.

Which would suit your needs more, acting on the [ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)'s [ItemActivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemactivate%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)?

**[Note: All of the links above contain example code]**

```
ListView listView1;

private void init_listView1() {
  listView1.ItemActivate += new EventHandler(listView_Focus);
  listView1.GotFocus += new EventHandler(listView_Focus);
}

private void listView_Focus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  int index = -1;
  if ((listView1.SelectedIndices != null) && (0 < listView1.SelectedIndices.Count)) {
    index = listView1.SelectedIndices[0];
    ListViewItem item = listView1.Items[index];
  } else {
    if (0 < listView1.Items.Count) {
      index = 0;
    }
  }
  if (-1 < index) {
    listView1.Items[index].Focused = true;
  }
}
```